# Is it possible for corosync / pacemaker to consider a node active only if a particular process is running?

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I want a node to be considered "online" (and thus able to get resources) only *after* it is ready for them (that is, a particular process is up and running.)

Is there a way to configure pacemaker to check if a particular process is running, and only then set the node "online"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`corosync` is for cluster memebership and `pacemaker` for resource management and node management, i think the only thing you can do is use in your resource a definition like this.

```
primitive Dummy1 ocf:pacemaker:Dummy \
        op monitor interval="60s" on-fail="fence"

crm configure property stonith-action=poweroff
```

When the monitor action of `Dummy1` will fail, the pacemaker will fence the node where the resource fail happened using the poweroff stonith action, in this way your node will be down and the status of node change from online to offline.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand how adding a Dummy resource helps me monitor that a particular custom process (not Pacemaker) is up and running.

Comment: that was an example, you need to set the attribute on-fail="fence" in your resource configuration, if you are using crmsh "crm configure"